# Import RSS feed from LinkedIn?

Tags: php, javascript, html, rss, linkedin-api

Is there any way of getting the RSS feed of a LinkedIn group (like this: http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Behance-Creatives-55523) to show on a webpage?

I would like to display the most recent discussion on a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no RSS feed for LinkedIn groups, as they all require the viewer to be a LinkedIn member to join (at a minimum).

You could use the [Groups API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api) and the [recommended](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/libraries-and-tools) PHP wrapper [Simple-LinkedIn](http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/) to get the recent posts from a given group, but the catch, as with all LinkedIn API integrations is thta the viewer must be authenticated against the API. SO on your custom page that shows recent discussion, the viewer would need to have authenticated against LinkedIn, and depending on the group permission, be a member of the group.

Comment: Thanks for that. Looks like a great resource on the Simple-LinkedIn site.

Comment: Paul, could you tell me if the Simple-LinkedIn will still work? My concern is that this stack is a few years old now and I haven't come across anything recent regarding the library. Thanks.